# What exactly are expressions, and statements in Lua?

Tags: lua, expression, statements

what really are expressions, and statements in Lua?
its often not that clear due to things like the vararg expression '...' and that nil/true/false are also expressions.

and are table accesses expressions? it seems to make sense, because you cant just write a table access in to the file and expect it too run.

Comment: where do complex expressions come in?

Comment: "*its often not that clear due to things like the vararg expression '...' and that nil/true/false are also expressions.*" What's not clear about that? Also the distinction between an "expression" and a "statement" is basically like those in most imperative languages. Python, JavaScript, C, C++, Java, C#, Go, Swift, Rust, the basic ideas are all the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Complete Syntax of Lua](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#9) has the formal specification. `stat` is statements and `exp` is expressions. Anyway, here's the summary of the specific bits you asked about:

> what really are expressions, and statements in Lua?

Basically, expressions are anything that evaluates to a value, and statements are things that get executed and can be separated by semicolons, and are usually each on their own line.

> its often not that clear due to things like the vararg expression '...' and that nil/true/false are also expressions.

You're right about those things being expressions. It doesn't make anything unclear, though.

> and are table accesses expressions?

Yes. They're covered by `var ::=  Name | prefixexp ‘[’ exp ‘]’ | prefixexp ‘.’ Name`, which is part of `exp` via `prefixexp`.